# Extra argument in call on a closure call

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Trying to implement firebase/firestore in iOS, adding the following gives me `Extra argument in call` error on `(snapshop , error)`.

```
T.subCollectionRef(of: parentDocument.ref).document(documentID).getDocument { snapshot, error in
    completion(Result(snapshot, error)
        .map { snapshot in snapshot.exists ? .init(snapshot: snapshot) : nil }
    )
}
```

https://github.com/sgr-ksmt/SwiftUI-Firebase-Todo/blob/master/FireTodo-w-SwiftUI/Sources/Models/FirestoreModel.swift#L44

PS: I'm a *super-noob* to swift.

Comment: What type does the callback of `getDocument` have? If it is a Result type, you could pretty much just pass it along

Answer (score 0):

I not quite sure what you want to achieve when you call `.map` on the `Result`.

There are two edge cases defined in the swift `Result` enum type:

- Either it is of type `.success<Success>`
- or it is of type `.failure<Failure>`

Taking a look into your `init` extension of `Result`:

```
public extension Result {
    init(_ success: Success?, _ failure: Failure?) {
        if let success = success {
            self = .success(success)
        } else if let failure = failure {
            self = .failure(failure)
        } else {
            fatalError("Illegal combination found.\n Success: \(success as Any), Failure: \(failure as Any)")
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that if the first parameter (`snapshot` in your case) is non-`nil`, you create a `.success` Result, else you create a `.failure` Result with the provided `error`. If both are `nil`, you crash with a `fatalError`

When you call `.map` on the `Result`, this will internally only be executed if the `Result` is `.success`, e.g. the `snapshot` is non-`nil`. Yet, in your map closure, you check if `snapshot.exists` and, if not, you return `nil`. But this will be illegal, because it would lead to a new `Result.success` with a `nil` associated value.

You have to check the logic of how you want the `.success` result be mapped to a new result type.

I guess what you *really* want is the following: If there is a `snapshot`, *and* `snapshot.exits` is true, then you want to call the completion handler with `Result.success`, else with `Result.failure`. Something *similar* to this:

```
T.subCollectionRef(of: parentDocument.ref).document(documentID).getDocument { snapshot, error in
    if let snapshot = snapshot, snapshot.exists {
      completion(Result.success(snapshot))
    } else {
      Result.failure(error)
    }
}
```